# How can I display the only the first two records per column in the database?

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

Here is the PHP I'm using.

```
echo "<td class='leftalign'>";
echo "<tr id='centered' >" . $row['Fund_Yield'] . "</td></tr>";
echo "<tr id='centered' >" . $row['Fund_Benchmark_Yield'] . "</tr>";
echo "<tr id='centered' >" . $row['Class_Yield'] . "</tr>";
echo "<tr id='centered' >" . $row['Special_Class_Yield'] . "</tr>";
echo "<tr id='centered' >" . $row['Plus_minus_Benchmark'] . "</tr>";
echo "<tr id='centered' >" . $row['Plus_Minus_Class'] . "</tr>";
echo "<tr id='centered' >" . $row['Plus_Minus_Special_Class'] . "</tr>";
echo "<tr id='centered' >" . $row['Percentile_Class'] . "</tr>";
echo "<tr id='centered' >" . $row['Percentile_Special_Class'] . "</tr>";

echo"</td>";
```

Each label contain 4 records but I only want to display the first two or whatever I specify.

Comment: You didn't post all your relevant code, but try to add "LIMIT 2" to your MySQL SELECT query

Comment: Your nesting of `<td>` and `<tr>` makes no sense either..

Comment: delete that first instance of `</td>` in your second line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would use `LIMIT` in your query http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm

Comment: But what if for a another column I need to display 3 for that one?

Comment: show us your `SELECT` query. Your question doesn't make sense now. You said you needed 2